# How do I make a Python array made up of multiples of (e.g) 3?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm making a program that counts from 1 to 1000 (printing each number) but changes the printed value at any multiple of 3. How do I make my array made up of multiples of a certain number without manually having to enter each multiple up to 1000? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @MarioIshac sorry to say, no. I'm very new to python and arrays and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine if a number is a multiple of another number you can use the modulus operator '%'. So to change the output based on whether the number is a multiple of 3 you could do:

```
for num in range(0,1001):
   if num % 3 ==0:
      print('multiple of 3')
   else:
      print(num)
```

If you specifically want an array of multiples you could do a variation of the above:

```
mult_arr = [ x for x in range(0,1001) if x%3==0]
```

Answer (score 1):

modulus % to check remainder

```
print(['3x' if i%3==0 else i for i in range(1,1001)])
```

To get only the multiples of 3:

```
print([i for i in range(1,1001) if i%3==0])
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as :

```
np.arange(0,1000,3) #or any N
```

Comment: This solution would include 0, which should not be included

Answer (score 1):

You could use the python modulo operator with 3, e.g. `6 % 3` = 0 whereas `7 % 3` = 1. If the result is 0, the numerator is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1):

Something a lot longer but more understandable for a beginner:

```py
multiplesOfThree = []
for i in range(0, 1000):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        multiplesOfThree.append(i)
```